# EF Core conditional Include on parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a question about that if is it possible to include a navigation property only when it is needed.

```
void FetchUser(bool includePhoneNumbers, bool includeAddresses)
{
}
```

How can I include these properties only when the related parameter is true?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

```
void FetchUser(bool includePhoneNumbers, bool includeAddresses)
{
    var query = dbContext.Users.AsQueryable();
    
    if (includePhoneNumbers)
    {
        query = query.Include(u => u.PhoneNumbers);
    }
    
    if (includeAddresses)
    {
        query = query.Include(u => u.Addresses);
    }
    
    var users = query.ToList();
}
```